# Python List Help (Find Biggest number)

Tags: python, string, list, numbers

Ok, I have this script that i wrote:

```
i=1024;
a=[0]*i;
for k in range(0,i):
    a[k]=(k*k*k*k-74*k*k+173) % 1000033
print a
```

I don't understand how to find the biggest number in the list AND its position.

Comment: ... It is? Looks like a polynomial and a modulus to me.

Comment: He's probably just being mean to the newbie.

Comment: I am a noob, but i think this is a good question to ask at my age (15).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep a running track, then you don't need the list:

```
largest = None
i = 1024

for k in range(i):
    a = (k ** 4 - 74 * k ** 2 + 173) % 1000033
    if not largest or largest[1] < a:
        largest = (k, a)

print(largest)
```

Output:

```
(2, 999926)
```

P.S. `i = 1048576` took a couple seconds and spat out:

```
(156865, 1000032L)
```

Note that it switched to long integers in there somewhere. This is with Python 2.6.1.

P.P.S. Also note that this method only finds the lowest index with the maximum. To get the highest index, replace the `<` with `<=`:

```
(843168, 1000032L)
```

Comment: I dont understand the line if not largest or largest[1] < a:
        largest = (k, a)

Comment: `not largest` is only `True` when `largest` is `None`, i.e. the first time through the loop. After the first time through, `largest` is a 2-tuple consisting of the index of the largest value (`largest[0]`), and the largest value itself (`largest[1]`), so the whole thing means "If this is the first pass, or `a` is larger than the largest seen so far, then set `largest` to `(k, a)`."

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way:

```
value = max(a)
index = a.index(value)
```

In your example, value is 999926 and index is 2.

Answer (score 3):

```
# create the list with a list comprehension
m = [(k*k*k*k-74*k*k+173) % 1000033 for k in range(i)]
# enumerate the values and pick the largest by value
pos, val = max(enumerate(m), key=lambda (pos, val): val)
```

Comment: If you could use a generator instead of a list comprehension, you'll save memory and cache thrashing with large `i`.

Answer (score 1):

```
m = max(a)
m_index = a.index(m)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [1,3,4,56,2,66,20,312]
print "%d found at index %d is the max of the list" % (max(lst), lst.index(max(lst)))
```